# How do I pass an object from jsp to controller with spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have a class User and a class Project which has an arraylist with users.
I have a Project page with a list of all my projects and when I click on one, it takes me to the page of that project by sending the id of that project in the URL.

On my detail project page I want to add users that I created.
The users are displayed on a modal in a table with a button to add them.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1 class="text-center">UserList</h1>
                    <br><br>
                    <table class="table table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Photo</th>
                                <th>Firstname</th>
                                <th>Lastname</th>
                                <th>Function</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <c:forEach var="u" items="${users}">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img src="${u.getPhoto()}"
                                             alt="Alternate Text" class="img-responsive" /></td>
                                    <td>${u.getFirstname()}</td>
                                    <td>${u.getLastname()}</td>
                                    <td>${u.getFunction()}</td>
                                    <td>${u.getEmail()}</td>
                                    <td><Button type="Button" class="btn btn-default">Add</button></td>
                                </tr> 
                            </c:forEach>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My question is how do I send the id of the user and the id of the project I want them to be added to my controller?

I know I can pass an id with the URL but I don't want to open a new page.

I want to send the ID of the user and the project to my controller by clicking on the add button to my controller so I can use those in my method called addUserToProject()

Comment: Can you provide you controller code please?

Comment: [This](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSP**

First, make a hidden input with selected project id, so you can get it later:

```
<input type="hidden" id="currentProjectId" value="12">
```

Second, set attribute **name** of add buttons equal **userId**:

```
<td><Button type="Button" name="${u.getId()}" class="btn btn-default">Add</button></td>
```

**Javascript:**

Define onclick linstener for each "add button" and get the current user id from the button:

```
   $(".btn").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         var currentProjectId= $('#currentProjectId').val();
         var userId = $(this).attr("name");

        addUser(currentProjectId, userId);

    });
```

Make **ajax request** and post the ids to controller:

```
function addUser(currentProjectId, selectedUserId) {

    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "/addUserToProject",
        data :{ projectId: currentProjectId, userId: selectedUserId}, 
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done : function(e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, controller accepts ids using **@RequestParam:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUserToProject", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody
String Submit(@RequestParam("projectId") Integer projectId ,@RequestParam("userId ") Integer userId ) {

   //insert user

    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: Like this: <input type="hidden" id="currentProjectId" value="${p.getProjectId()}">. And you get the value: var currentProjectId= $('#currentProjectId').val();

Comment: How can i check if the AJAX script reaches my controller, because i've tried your solution but i can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Right click -> inspect elements to see messages from the tab **console**. Also you can see ajax requests from the tab **Network**. See: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: Please send the error. Also make sure you have delete space from **@RequestParam("userId ")** to **@RequestParam("userId")**

Comment: https://gyazo.com/213e39c1b10a54f83ead816d22209154 this is the error im getting right now.

Comment: That means that /addUserToProject path is not defined. Can you send the complete code? (view and controller). Οtherwise I can not help.

Comment: add alert(currentProjectId  + " " + userId); before ajax request to ensure that  you pass correct parameters and convert them into string.  Also open **Network tab** before press the button to check the request.

Comment: The alert works but when i convert them from var to string it doesnt work anymore.

Comment: See this example is exactly what you are trying to achive:https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-refactoring-a-jquery-ajax-post-example/

Answer (score 0):

From a rendered page you only have two options either you do a normal form post or use Ajax if you dont want to open a new url.